# Github Actions CI. xcodebuild: error: 'ProjectName/ProjectName.xcodeproj' does not exist

Tags: xcode, github-actions, gitlab-ci, cicd

I first time try to add Github Actions. It's a simple project without 3d dependencies.
My steps: 1. Create a remote repo, 2. Push local into remote, 3. Create `yml`, 4. Test.

My current `yml` with errors:

```
name: Swift

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build-and-test:

  runs-on: macos-latest

  steps:
  - name: Select Xcode
    run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_14.2.app

  - name: Build and test
    run: xcodebuild clean build test -project ProjectName/ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme 'ProjectNameUnitTests' -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

After running this, I have: `xcodebuild: error: 'ProjectName/ProjectName.xcodeproj' does not exist.`

If I remove project, then I have error: `xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/runner/work/ProjectName_Test/ProjectName_Test does not contain an Xcode project, workspace or package.`
If it make sense, my remote repo named `ProjectName_Test`, when project named just `ProjectName`.

I tried different ways and can't find solution in other topics. If you know, how to fix it, please, help)

Comment: The checkout step is missing. Add `- uses: actions/checkout@v3` before issuing any commands that need code to work on. See https://github.com/actions/checkout for more details.

Comment: You're welcome! Always keep in mind that the GHA runner is a different machine and you need your code there first if the subsequent steps need it. Otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Azeem said, I needed to add `- uses: actions/checkout@v3`, it helped)